# Simple for Pro´s: For what is the name in the (brackets)?

Tags: javascript

you pros.

I am a noob in Js and i started learning some time ago. But i do not get the use for the name in a function. I´ve saw no description for that in any tutorial, so i came to you! And Sorry for this type of Question. ex:

```
var hexagon = function (hover/THIS POINT) {
var hex1 = document.getElementById('hexagon1_work');
hex1.addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
    document.getElementsByClassName('content')[0]
        .style.backgroundColor = '#000000';
});
hex1.addEventListener('mouseout', function(){
    document.getElementsByClassName('content')[0]
        .style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
});

var hex2 = document.getElementById('hexagon2_work');
hex2.addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
    document.getElementsByClassName('content')[0]
        .style.backgroundColor = '#EAE080';
});
hex2.addEventListener('mouseout', function(){
    document.getElementsByClassName('content')[0]
        .style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
});
```

That would help me alot.
And are there other ways to write a function? ex:

```
function() { ... }
```

Thank you. :)
Mike

Comment: `function name(arg1, arg2, ..., argN) { // body }`. Documentation shows many examples: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FFunction

Comment: so the name in this case stands for the variable?

Comment: Yes, they are semantically the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to write a function in Javascript.

**An example of a named (not anonymous) function**:

```
function myFunction(a, b) {
    return a * b;             
}
```

myFunction is the name of the function and the things in the brackets are arguments. They are useful because they make it possible to do the same operation for different values without code duplication.

**An anonymous function**:

```
var myFunction = function(a,b) {
  return a * b; 
};
```

In this case, myFunction is not the name of the function but a variable which has the anonymous function as its value.

**Creating a function by calling constuctor**:

```
var myFunction = new Function("a","b","return a * b;");
```

---

All of the above do the same and you can call all of them like:

```
var x = myFunction(4, 3); //result is 12
var x = myFunction(2, 5); //result is 10
```

---

More info (easy to understand for beginners): [w3schools tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp), [wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/JavaScript/Functions)